# how to connect to different Hosts in elasticsearch using Node Client

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, scala-2.11, elasticsearch-java-api

i am using ElasticSearch node client to perform queries but i want to connect to  different IP address then localhost, I want to achieve this

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

thing in node client

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("yourcluster").client(true).node();
Client client = node.client();
```

please help me, I want to use `Node Client` with other hosts not `TransportClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node client automatically discovers all the nodes of the cluster because it's actually a part of the cluster itself, you don't need to list the hosts manually. But if your cluster resides in another network which can't be discovered automatically you may also specify at least one cluster host with settings.

```
Settings.Builder settings = Settings.builder()
.put("path.home", ".")
.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts","192.168.1.1");

Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings)
      .clusterName("elasticsearch")
      .client(true)
      .node();
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Comment: but what if i want to connect to a different ip address's ?

Comment: what if elasticsearch server is running on some ip address 192.168.1.2 and the application that is creating a client is on another server eg 192.168.1.4 then how our app knows that Elasticsearch server is running on this 192.168.1.2 ip ?